# Implementing spring cache plugin in grails

Tags: spring, caching, grails

I want to implement the spring cache plugin in my grails app and I have installed the plugin using the install-plugin command.

As per spring cache's [documentation](http://gpc.github.com/grails-springcache/docs/guide/single.html) in my **resources.groovy** I have the cache configuration

```
venueCache(org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean) { bean ->
    cacheManager = ref("springcacheCacheManager")
    eternal = true
    diskPersistent = false
    cacheName = "venueCache"
}
```

and in the controller I have `@Cacheable("venueCache")` on my show action

```
@Cacheable("venueCache")
def show(id) {
 ...
}
```

But whenever I start the app and hit the URL multiple times, it doesn't seem to give from the cache. It logs the statement :

`web.GrailsFragmentCachingFilter  - No cacheable annotation found for GET:/grails/venue/action-router.dispatch grails.plugin.springcache.web.FilterContext@4f7351e4`

Is there anything that I am missing in my configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was some stupid overlooking on my part - I had to import grails.plugin.springcache.annotations.* for the @Cacheable annotation , but instead the STS auto imported the Spring Cacheable annotation. Changed the import to grails.plugin.springcache.annotations.* and all working well